Coordinates of an NetCDF file comes flipped out
I have created a new variable called 'temperature' that represents the temperature gradient to detect oceanic thermal fronts. One issue I encounter when plotting this variable is that the terrestrial part, which includes Africa and part of Brazil (the Atlantic Ocean), appears reversed. Africa appears on the left and Brazil on the right, as if the signs of latitudes and longitudes were reversed - Ocean Fronts in the East Tropical Atlantic.

Initially, the map appeared reversed, but I transposed the file to correct it, yet it remains flipped. I'm unsure how to adjust it so that the latitude and longitude are correct with their signs. Thank you very much for the help; I'm quite stuck!
#Set the path fot the NetCDF
ncfile <- "C:/Users/mdolores.riesgo/Desktop/PhD_MB/PhD_Documents/Chapters/01_Chapter/01_RawData/CopernicusDataProducts/Var_Calculated/Fronts/2018/CMEMS_TropicalAtlantic_thetao_Aug2018_front.nc"

#Import the netCDF
nc <- nc_open(ncfile)
print(nc) #details about the product
dimensions <- names(nc$dim)
print(dimensions)
variables <- names(nc$var)
print(variables)

lon <- ncvar_get(nc, "longitude")
lat <- ncvar_get(nc, "latitude")
gradfront <- ncvar_get(nc, "Temperature")
gradfront <- t(gradfront)
grad <- raster(gradfront)
extent(grad) <- c(min(lon), max(lon), min(lat), max(lat))
entent(grad)
#The result
#class      : Extent 
#xmin       : -43.16667 
#xmax       : 19.33333 
#ymin       : -26.5 
#ymax       : 29.41667 
plot(grad) 


This may not be possible to solve without a minimal, reproducible example when asking a question. This link has some really useful guidance regarding how to create an MRE, and how to share example data in particular. In your case it is likely that your data are too large to dput() so perhaps a download link would be appropriate.

The reason you need to share your data is because we can't see all the steps taken to generate your data. Do you have the original data that you used to derive your dataset? Does that data plot correctly? A download link to the original link would also be useful.

And I'll toss in, it would be helpful to see the original Copernicus datafile just to doublecheck that it is encoded correctly, i.e., in a way that netCDF tools understand. Not that I expect otherwise, but I have run into trouble with Copernicus GRIB output.

Like some of the comments indicated, you should really provide more information in your question so that others can "play around" with your data and code to find an answer. A link to your data file would have been very helpful. Despite that, the issue is clear as this is common for anyone who has worked more than just a little bit with netCDF data in R.
I could not find your file on CMEMS so I am using another file here but the principles are the same.
The underlying problem
In R, data in matrices and arrays are stored in column-major order (Fortran style). That means, in simple terms, that data goes from the top-left position down and then by column across to the right. Most mapping software, including the GDAL library underlying raster, uses row-major order (C style): rows first, moving down. When plotting the data, the simple approach to correct this, for a 2D matrix, is to transpose the data using t(). This obviously didn't work for you. The reason for this is shown below.
Use the right tools
The raster package has been superseded by package terra, from the same developers. Use terra because it is much easier and faster than raster.
Similarly, I use package ncdfCF to access netCDF data. It is a lot easier to work with than ncdf4.
Looking at the data
> library(ncdfCF)

> src <- "~/20140815120000-ESACCI-L4_GHRSST-SST-GMPE-GLOB_CDR2.0-v02.0-fv01.0.nc"
> ds <- open_ncdf(src)

# The variables in the file
> names(ds)
[1] "field_name"         "analysed_sst"       "standard_deviation" "analysis_number"
[5] "median_type"        "anomaly_fields"     "gradient_fields" 

# Look at the SST variable
> sst <- ds[["analysed_sst"]]
> sst
Variable: [7] analysed_sst | median SST from GMPE

Dimensions:
 id axis name long_name                   length values                
 0  X    lon                              1440   [-179.875 ... 179.875]
 1  Y    lat                               720   [-89.875 ... 89.875]  
 2  T    time reference time of sst field    1   [2014-08-15 12:00:00] 
### (Attributes omitted for brevity)

The problem now becomes clear: the lat dimension runs from its lowest value to its highest value. This is a common pattern in netCDF files that conform to the CF Metadata Conventions (as virtually all ocean and climate products do). In terms of the storage mode discussed above, data in this file goes from the bottom-left up to the top, then per column to the right!
ncdfCF solution
The ncdfCF package automatically corrects for any arrangement of the axes in the data file. It doesn't do any plotting, but you can easily export the data to a terra::SpatRaster for plotting and any other spatial analysis:
# sst is a "CFVariable": all the metadata is there, but the data itself has 
# not yet been read for efficiency reasons. Getting the data for your study
# area is easy enough:
> sst_data <- sst$subset(list(lon = c(-43.16667, 19.33333), lat = c(-26.5, 29.41667)))
> sst_data
<Data> analysed_sst 
Long name: median SST from GMPE 

Values: [285.26 ... 301.94] kelvin
    NA: 18540 (33.1%)

Axes:
 id axis name length values               
 -1 X    lon  250    [-43.125 ... 19.125] 
 -1 Y    lat  224    [-26.375 ... 29.375] 
    T    time   1    [2014-08-15 12:00:00]

Attributes:
### (Attributes omitted for brevity)

# sst_data is a "CFData" object, the data has been read from file. You can
# export this to an array or directly to a `terra::SpatRaster`
> r <- sst_data$terra()
> plot(r)


terra solution
Note that if you open the netCDF file with terra directly, the correction of the latitude coordinate and the storage order is automatically made (it is a known and common issue, after all):
library(terra)

x <- rast(src)
# Figure out which layer to plot
# Crop the data to your study area
plot(x["{your layer}"])

However, since you are working on your PhD I am assuming that you need to process the data in R. terra is not a good solution for that as it does not provide access to all the details in the netCDF file, nor does it fully interpret the metadata. Ocean netCDF files tend to be far more complicated and requiring interpretation of the metadata than general-purpose tools like terra support. If you need to write any processing functions yourself, use a package that is focused on netCDF.
Mucha suerte con tus investigaciones.

You can directly open most standard NetCDF files with gridded data terra like this:
x <- terra::rast(ncfile)

Or to pick a sub-dataset (if there are any)
y <- terra::rast(ncfile, "Temperature")

To capture multiple sub-datasets (if there are any)
z <- terra::sds(ncfile)

This is a much less error-prone approach than trying to do things "by hand" via ncdf4 other packages. Most people using these packages directly get the coordinates wrong.
If you want see the associated metadata, you can do
terra::describe(ncfile)

or (as you know)
nc <- ncdf4::nc_open(ncfile)
print(nc)
ncdf4::nc_close(nc)


Thank you so much for the answers!! I have solved the problem transposing the data with t()!!
